# GWT Platform with REST dispatch: get http status code from exception handler

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I'm usng GWTP rest dispath with ResourceDelegate and I want to catch all exceptions in client REST requests.
My REST backend return:

- 401 or 403 status codes if no authorization/forbidden
- 500 for other
  errors

So, I have added common handler to RestDispatchAsyncModule:

```
new RestDispatchAsyncModule.Builder().exceptionHandler(MyRestExceptionHandler.class);
```

**MyRestExceptionHandler.java:**

```
public class MyRestExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public Status onFailure(Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof ActionException){
            ActionException a = (ActionException)e;
            // How to get HTTP status code and response body here?
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I found that all REST exception are instances of ActionException class.
How can I get HTTP status code and http response body inside MyRestExceptionHandler?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use RestDispatchHooks instead of ExceptionHandler.

**AppRestDispatchHooks.java:**

```
public class AppRestDispatchHooks implements RestDispatchHooks {
    @Override
    public void onExecute(RestAction<?> action) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(RestAction<?> action, Response response, Object result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(RestAction<?> action, Response response, Throwable caught) {
        GWT.log("Status code:"+ response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

**Installing module:**

```
install(new RestDispatchAsyncModule.Builder()
        .dispatchHooks(AppRestDispatchHooks.class)
        .build())
```